# Запись в базу MySQL через PHP

Tags: mysqli, php, mysql

Собственно, вот он код:

```
$fl = file('allfile.csv');
$t_fl = count($fl);
$mysql_req = array();
for ($i=0; $i <=5 ; $i++) {
$item = explode("'\'", $fl[$i]);
$IDcategory = 101000149;
$prise = $item[8];
$prise = tofloat($prise);
$flags = $prise*10/100;
$prise = ($prise-$flags)*53;
$pr_1 = $item[10];
$pr_1 = tofloat($pr_1);
$flags = $pr_1*10/100;
$pr_1 = ($pr_1-$flags)*53;
$pr_2 = $item[16];
$pr_2 = tofloat($pr_1);
$flags = $pr_2*10/100;
$pr_2 = ($pr_2-$flags)*53;
$str_name =  $item[0];
$str_name = str_replace("`", "", $str_name);
$name_en = str_replace("'", "", $str_name);
$stock = 10000000;
$code = $item[2]."-".$item[4];
$sh_daesc = $item[1];
$desc_en = $item[1].",".$item[2].",".$item[4].",".str_replace("'", "", $item[3]).","."<b>Мелкий опт:</b> от 0 до 10000 - ".$pr_1.","."<b>Крупный опт:</b> от 0 до 10000000 - ".$pr_2;
$title_en = "Электронные компоненты ".$name_en."-".$item[4];
$m_desc = $title_en." ".$item[1];
$m_key = "Электронные компоненты, ".$item[4].",".str_replace("'", "", $item[3]);
$slug = $name_en;
$name_ru = $name_en;
$sh_daesc_ru = $sh_daesc;
$desc_ru = $desc_en;
$title_ru = $title_en;
$m_desc_ru = $m_desc;
$m_key_ru = $m_key;  
$res = "INSERT INTO SC_products (categoryID,Price,in_stock,enabled,product_code,name_en,brief_description_en,description_en,meta_title_en,meta_description_en,
meta_keywords_en,slug,name_ru,brief_description_ru,description_ru,meta_title_ru,meta_description_ru,meta_keywords_ru,ordering_available) VALUES ('$IDcategory',
    '$prise','$stock',1,'$code','$name_en','$sh_daesc','$desc_en','$title_en','$m_desc','$m_key','$slug','$name_ru',
    '$sh_daesc_ru','$desc_ru','$title_ru','$m_desc_ru','$m_key_ru',1)";
mysqli_query($link, $res); 
}
```

Проблема в том, что в файле 50к записей, а записывает в базу только одну! Почему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ошибки по коду:

1. `for ($i=0; $i <=5 ; $i++)` - почему ограничиваем максимум 5 записей? Тут, судя по логике, нужно читать весь файл.
2. Зачем так сложно читать файл? В PHP есть нормальный функции для работы с CSV файлами fgetcsv?
3. Повторяющиеся операции `$prise = $item[8]; $prise = tofloat($prise);$flags = $prise*10/100;$prise = ($prise-$flags)*53;` вынеси в отдельную функцию - читать удобнее будет.
4. Записывать 1 строку в базу 1 запросом - кучеряво живете? Лучше  вставлять порциями (я в свое время вставлял по 500 записей за раз (небольшими опытами получилось оптимальное время). Как пример: что вам лучше - 10 раз сбегать в магазин, принося каждый раз по 1 бут. пива, или раз сбегать и принести 10 бутылок?
5. Если у вас php >=5.5, смотри, как юзать генераторы [тут](http://habrahabr.ru/post/164173/), - скрипт будет работать лучше, не пожирая память.
6. Зачем вот такие присваивания `$IDcategory = 101000149; $stock = 10000000;` делать в цикле, если они от него не зависят? Типа повторение - мать заикания?
7. И вообще надо на PDO переходить уже.

Перепишите

```
mysqli_query($link, $res);
```

на вот это

```
If (mysqli_query($link, $res))
{
  echo 'Строка номер-'.$i.' успешно добавлена в базу';
}
else
{
  echo 'Ошибка при добавлении строки -'.$i.'. Описание ошибки:'.mysqli_error($link);
}
```

и посмотрите какой будет результат)

```
Duplicate entry '2147483647' for key 'PRIMARY
```

Целое число нормального размера. Диапазон со знаком от -2147483648 до 2147483647.

У вас это поле указано как INT - и счетчик вышел за диапазон возможных значений.

Для решения данного вопроса необходимо понять БИЗНЕС ЛОГИКУ данной таблицы - что она хранит в вашем приложении.

Если бизнес логика позволяет сбрасывать счетчик (это только в том случае если в других таблицах нет ссылок на строки этой таблицы), либо увеличивать диапазон - но если вы уже вышли за рамки данного диапазона - то нада думать - так как вы можете быстро выйти и из другого диапазона.

Comment: Покажите первые 5 строк файла  - возможно, запись не идет по причине нехватки данных для записи, и mysql возвращает ошибку. Какую именно строку сохраняет в базу - 1 или 5?  
Обновил ответ.

Comment: Интересное замечание! Выдает: 
Ошибка при добавлении строки -1. Описание ошибки:Duplicate entry '2147483647' for key 'PRIMARY'
Но почему? Key же имеет значение AI в базе!

Comment: Тогда код CREATE таблицы в студию. ) Обновил ответ. ) Давно код работать-то перестал? Я так понимаю, он некоторое время удачно работал.

Answer (score 1):

Ого вот это код. Это похоже на Webasyst. У меня реализовано так, обновляется база каждые 20 минут, 7-8 тыс позиций - 4-5 секунд

```
$file = './csv/file.csv';

$fin = fopen($file,'rb') or die('cant open file');
$mysqli->query("LOCK TABLES SC_products WRITE;");
while (($data=fgetcsv($fin,1000,";"))!==FALSE) {
    if(file_exists($dir."p".$data[0].".jpg"))
         $picture = 1;
    else $picture = 0;
    $res=$mysqli->query("SELECT categoryID FROM `SC_products` WHERE productID = '$data[0]'");

$number = $res->num_rows;

if($number>0) {
    $mysqli->query ("UPDATE SC_products SET Price='$data[1]',in_stock='$data[2]',enabled=1,date_modified=now(), name_en='$data[3]',name_ru='$data[3]',product_code='$data[0]',default_picture='$picture' WHERE productID ='$data[0]'");
    //printf("%d Обновлено записей\n", $mysqli->affected_rows);
    $done++;
}
else {
    $mysqli->query ("INSERT INTO SC_products(productID,categoryID,Price,in_stock,enabled,date_added,date_modified,name_en,name_ru,product_code,default_picture,ordering_available) VALUES('$data[0]','368','$data[1]','$data[2]',1,now(),now(),'$data[3]','$data[3]','$data[0]','$picture','1')");
            //printf("%d Добавлено товаров.\n", $mysqli->affected_rows);
            //echo "Запись обновлена<br />\n";
    $d++;
}
//printf("%d Row inserted.\n", $number); 
//$done++;
$res->close();
}

$mysqli->query("UNLOCK TABLES;");
fclose($fin);
$mysqli->close(); 
echo "Обновлено товаров: $done<br />\n";
echo "Добавлено товаров: $d<br />\n";
```